# How to plot a horizontal line in excel from a single value?

Tags: excel

Is there a way to plot a single horizontal line in excel using the value from a single cell? So without having to create a column filled with the same value for every point?

Edit: I'm trying to add the horizontal line to an existing lineplot

Comment: You'll need at least two values to form a line

Comment: create a second data series, take your min/max values for your x-axis and give plot the same y-axis value.  set to line or add a trendline to the data if you're using scatter plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to enter the value in the first and last row of data.

1) insert your chart

2) Right-click on it and choose "Select Data Source" from the drop-down menu

3) Select your series on the left hand side of the dialog box

4) Click on "Hidden and Empty Cells"

5) In the resulting dialog box, select "Connect data points with line

[image]

Comment: Sorry I'm missing something... in point 3) I don't have a series, I have a single number

Comment: "You'll need to enter the value in the first and last row of data."

Comment: Ok, so you mean that if I have a series of 50 values from 1 to 50 (so 50 rows) I write my target value in row 1 and row 50 and leave all the rest empy?

Comment: That's exactly right. You need two points to define a line, otherwise Excel has no way of "knowing" you want a horizontal one.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new "Name" (Formulas/Name Manager) with the formula:

```
=SEQUENCE(1,[number of datapoints],[value that we want to plot],0)
```

Then we select the chart, go to Chart Design/Select Data, and Edit our Series. In Values, we need to add:

```
='[Sheet name]'![Name we gave to the "Name" we created]
```

This works for Charts of dynamic sizes, since we can use COUNT to know how many datapoints we have. It also updates when we change the value we want to plot.